In my react native app , I am using height and width in % . Then the inner views are not visible . But when I use height:300 or width:300 it is . Why?
import { StyleSheet, Text, View, TouchableOpacity } from 'react-native';
import React from 'react';
import globalStyles from '../../Utils/globalStyles';
import Header from '../../Components/Header';

function SelectQuestionTypePage() {
    return (
        <View style={globalStyles.container}>
            <Header />
            <Text style={styles.textStyle}>Choose your question type</Text>
            <TouchableOpacity >  
                <View style={{ flexDirection: 'column', height: '80%', width: '80%', marginTop: 50 }}>
                    <View style={{ flex: 1, backgroundColor: 'red' }} />
                    <View style={{ flex: 2, backgroundColor: 'darkorange' }} />
                    <View style={{ flex: 3, backgroundColor: 'green' }} />
                </View>
            </TouchableOpacity>
        </View>
    );
}

export default SelectQuestionTypePage;

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    textStyle: {
        color: 'white',
        fontSize: 20,
        fontWeight: 'bold',
    },
});

Expected Behavior is to see something of this, given in the picture

Meanwhile, current behavior doesn't achieve the same. What could be the reason for it?
